# parallize postgres queries with bash and psql?

Tags: linux, bash, postgresql, psql

I'm trying to run a series of postgres functions/stored-procedures that operate on separate tables in parallel using bash + psql as follows:

```
psql -d samples_20160612_0616 -c "select insert_function('2016-6-14 20:00'::timestamp, '2016-6-14 21:00'::timestamp)" &
psql -d samples_20160612_0616 -c "select insert_function('2016-6-15 19:00'::timestamp, '2016-6-15 20:00'::timestamp)" &
psql -d samples_20160612_0616 -c "select insert_function('2016-6-15 20:00'::timestamp, '2016-6-15 21:00'::timestamp)" &
psql -d samples_20160612_0616 -c "select insert_function('2016-6-16 19:00'::timestamp, '2016-6-16 20:00'::timestamp)" &
psql -d samples_20160612_0616 -c "select insert_function('2016-6-16 20:00'::timestamp, '2016-6-16 21:00'::timestamp)"
```

For some reason it seems that instead of being run in parallel as expected, the statements are run serially.

What am I doing wrong here?  Shouldn't this run in parallel?